# How to check if item exists Unit test ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, unit-testing

So, I'm kind of new to this. Both, `lists` and `product` return null, but I can't figure out why.

```
[TestClass]
    public class ProductUnitTest
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        [TestMethod]
        public void ProductExistsId()
        {
            var list = db.Products.ToList();
            var product = db.Products.Find(1);
            Assert.IsTrue(list.Contains(product));
        }

    }
```

`ApplicationDbContext` works correctly in other parts of the project. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have some test methods that use `db` before this one? Maybe in those methods something is messed.

Comment: The connectionString is probably not picked up correctly in the test project, and usually you don't want to run tests on the actual database in a unit test anyways since you're not testing the database engine/framework, but the business logic. I would skip this test and focus on the associated classes and methods. If you really want to simulate database operations I would recommend mocking https://github.com/moq/moq4

Comment: @MartinÅhlin yeah, you're right. Now I understand it.